# Can I install .SIS files from within an NokiaQt Symbian application?

Tags: qt, symbian

I'm developing something like a app-store in Android/iOS. Hence I like to know whether I can trigger the installation of downloaded .SIS files to the user, prompting him accept permissions, if any and confirm the installation.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Use [RSWInstLauncher](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/SW_Installer_Launcher_API) (NOT RSWInstSilentLauncher unless you want to avoid all user interaction)
2. Open the SIS file directly - RApaLsSession::StartDocument()

Comment: I think that's the one required, thanks. Will have to link the other SDK then as well. thx. The additional SDKs are available here: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/SDK_API_Plug-in

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. I have done it for one of my client's application. It does not need any user interaction.

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WRT widgets like the OVI store. See [Forum Nokia](http://forum.nokia.com) for examples.